Behaviour of light in non-Newtonian fluids
So if a ray of light is passed through a  cuboidal glass tub, and refraction occurs for the first time and if force is applied on the the fluid laterally, the viscosity  would vary and so would it's optical density, so assumed that the reaction time (after light passes the tub and first refraction occurs but before it passes through the fluid completely) is faster than speed of light and force is applied before the light ray completely passes through the fluid, would another refraction occur considering that the medium is translucent in solidified state.

Welcome to Physics SE. This seems to be a very complicated scenario, and varying things faster than the speed of light sounds alarming. Are you actually interested in a real world scenario, or is this some attempt to create a 'paradox'? Change of optical properties at speeds high enough to affect the propagating light beam deferentially can often arise in non-linear optics. For example there are things like self-focusing. Are you familiar with this literature?

Scattering of light on sound-wave induced variations in refractive index is also pretty well known. Reverse processes, light creating sound should also be possible. Basically, these are all forms of photon-phonon interactions in solids.
